Fail to populate Transaction

Transaction.transaction.message.accountKeys and transaction.transaction.message.instructions are undefined

        const transaction = await solanaConnection.getTransaction(signature, {
            commitment: 'finalized',
            maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 2
        });

        //https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/31916ae5d4fb29f239c63252a59745e33a6979ea/packages/library-legacy/src/transaction/legacy.ts#L930
        // transaction.transaction.message.accountKeys and transaction.transaction.message.instructions are undefined
        if(transaction.transaction.message.accountKeys) {
            const transactionMessage = Transaction.populate(transaction.transaction.message, transaction.transaction.signatures);
            console.log(transactionMessage)
        }


There's an error in how you're fetching the transaction, and so the returned transaction has no data. Since maxSupportedTransactionVersion should be 0, try doing this:
        const transaction = await solanaConnection.getTransaction(signature, {
            commitment: 'finalized',
            maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0
        });

